# Find first pattern and retrieve data up to next pattern find

Tags: python, regex

I have a string as follows:

```
my_str = "808c000003a185c50cd9b00285e78220500ac56a1c5ca5a1004b2404aa412f058c0a1ba85820cc8208080813c7040a228e0133ca5aca03a2829012533208704411004010808c001003a1c5c50cd9b00285e7822"
```

I want to group together the strings if they meet a condition

Whenever there is a sequence of '0808', I want this and the following text UP TO  the point of the next 0808 pattern etc..

```
result = re.findall(r'(0808)', my_str)
```

This just gives me a list of the pattern itself.

I want it to include the pattern and the following text. Something fundamentally wrong with the regex i'm inputting.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Why do this with regex? You can use e.g. `str.find` to get the first and second indexes of the substring `'0808'`, then slice out the part you want.

Comment: Split with `(?=0808)` if you have Python 3.7. You may also try `re.findall(r'08080.*?(?=0808|\Z)', s)`

Comment: What if there is no _next 0808 pattern_?

Answer (score 0):

`0808.*?(?=0808)`

This looks for the `0808` string then lazily matches 0 or more chars afterwards up to the point of the lookahead to `0808`

This will return a match for each selection of 0808foobar matches